# Is possible to change the "add" text on semantic-ui-dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I would like to know if this is possible, if yes, what setting should I change?

The add appears when type a value that isn't listed on dropdown

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.ui.dropdown')
        .dropdown({
            clearable: true,
            allowAdditions: true,
            hideAdditions: false,

            onAdd: function (addedValue, addedText, $addedChoice) {
                console.log('teste');
            },

            onChange: function (value, text, $choice) {
                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('clear');
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropdownHospital" name="hospitais" class="ui search selection dropdown"
style="margin:0">
<option hidden selected value="">Hospitais</option>
<option value="1">Hospital São Luis</option>
<option value="2">Hospital Sírio Libanês</option>
<option value="3">Hospital Albert Einstein</option>
<option value="4">Hospital ABC</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add` text is something hardcoded by the library. Because it's rendered in the DOM. You can manipulate this with some jQuery.

The solution is not perfect and is hacky, but it gives a hint of a work around. It now only deletes the add after the second key stroke.

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="menu transition visible" style="display: block !important;">
    <div class="addition item selected" data-text="xcx" data-value="xcx">Add <b>xcx</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML that is rendered for the add option. When we attach keyup event to the dropdown we can change the add text with jQuery's `text`. See the snippet.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
clearable: true,
allowAdditions: true,
hideAdditions: false,

onAdd: function(addedValue, addedText, $addedChoice) {
  console.log('teste');
},

onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('clear');
}
});

$('.ui.dropdown').on('keyup', 'input:text', function() {
  const element = $(this).parent('.ui.dropdown').find('div.menu.transition.visible > div.addition.item.selected');
  element.text(element.attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<select class="ui dropdown search selection ">
  <span class="text">add options</span>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
</select>
```

The solution is to use `<span class="text">add options</span>` to alter the text of your dropdown.

A quick gaze into the documentation brings a lot of joy:
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: Thanks Mouser, but the "Add" appears to me when I type a value that isn't listed on dropdown

Comment: @LeonardoLima, check the new "solution".